# in-car server, avoid disk error when power interruption?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ups

guys I have a low powered 1U server in my car which collect some data, but when I stop my car and remove my key, the power for the linux box will be cut immediately for the computer. And power back when key is in.

There will be 1-2 MySQL insert per minute into the disk.

Questions:

1. Can I mount OS drive read-only for entire operation? and rest writable, to ensure OS will not be corruption?
2. Can I use a UPS to issue shutdown command and restart command when power cuts and back. (never used any UPS)

Comment: Sounds like you should consider designing the system for a car instead of using a standard PC. There used to be plenty of websites out there with tons of information.

Answer (score 5):

There are special power supplies available which run direct from the battery feed and monitor the accessory line.  When the power is turned off it performs a clean ACPI shutdown using the power from the battery.  Turning the ignition back on signals to the PSU to turn the power back on again.  As they are 12V power supplies and not mains there is no need for such things as inverters, and they are consequently more power efficient.

Take a look at [these](http://linitx.com/viewcategory.php?catid=154&pp=149,152,154) for example from my favourite UK supplier.

Comment: What about branded UPS? because I would like to make rack server later for more complicated applications ( like video recognition?) do they provide clean ACPI shutdown and restart job?

Comment: +1: @c2h2 - For DC-DC CarPC the best 'brand' I know of is Opus Solutions (http://www.opussolutions.com).  I have used a 90W Opus DC-DC for years, works great.  Includes a configurble shutdown controller, and ignition off/on/accessory mode detection (so it survives the crank, and switching between 'on' and 'accessory').

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Take the HD out of the equation. Try using a bootable CD instead of a hard drive.